# How do I hide QDialog that has Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose flag?

Tags: qt, windows, qdialog

I have a `QDialog` that was created with `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag. When specific event happens I need to hide the dialog and restore it later upon another specific event. If I make a call to `QWidget::hide()` the dialog object is deleted (due to `WA_DeleteOnClose`) which doesn't work for me.

Unfortunately I can't unset/reset `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` in runtime for certain technical reasons.

The question is: how do I effectively hide `QDialog` so that it's not visible but still exists? I tried

```
QDialog* pDlg = ...;
QSizePolicy newSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
pDlg->setSizePolicy(newSizePolicy);
pDlg->setMinimumSize(0,0);
pDlg->resize(0,0);
```

but this didn't work. Might it be that I can move the dialog outside the desktop? Or...

I'm solely on Windows if it matters.

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you temporary remove `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute before you hind the dialog and restore it when it becomes visible?

Comment: What happens if you use `showMinimized()`?

Comment: **Try pDlg->hide()** As I said the dialog object is being destructed.             

**What happens if you use showMinimized()**
The dialog gets minimized as if it belongs to the desktop.
http://i.imgur.com/TK2mycC.png             

**temporary remove Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose attribut** 
Unfortunately I can't. The dialog might be bound to a background thread and when the thread completes it hides the dialog. If I remove the flag the dialog will stay forever and contain outdated data.

Comment: If you can't temporarily remove the flag, you'll probably have to do it without `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` at all and implement some other deletion logic (e.g. delete it manually when your thread finishes)